# Feed Android sensors with fake data

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I would like to ask if there is a way to feed Android sensors with fake data.

For example you can feed GPS sensor with mock locations using:

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
geo fix -82.411629 28.054553
OK
```

Question 1:
Can you do the same with real devices?

Question 2:
Can you do the same with other sensors (eg. accerelometer) as well?

Comment: for gps u can use gpx file in emulator

Comment: The question title is ambiguous: it seems that you want to provide fake data to the sensors... While I guess you want to process some fake data AS IF it came out from sensors.